# mySQL - Don't fetch posts multiple times if it the have same value in a spesific row

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting posts using;

```
SELECT * from posts order by id DESC limit 3
```

Table structure is;

### ID | content | author | date

The problem is, it also fetches posts which have same value in content row.

Result

```
1- New cars in Oklahoma
2- New cars in Washington
3- New cars in Oklahoma
```

Now, lets say some posts have exactly same values in content row, how can I fetch these post only 1 time, so that it fetches like

```
1- New cars in Oklahoma
2- New cars in Washington
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're fine with skipped some rows (since they are repeated):

```
SELECT * from posts group by `content` order by id DESC limit 3
```

This will show group all rows that contain the same content.